# JavaScript biased results?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, random

Let's say I have two items in an array, e.g:

```
["a", "b"]
```

Now let's say I have a function called random that chooses a random item from this array, e.g:

```
function random() {
  // do awesome random stuff here...
  return random_choice;
}
```

How can I get the `random` function to return `"a"` 80% of the time and `"b"` 20% of the time?

I'm not really sure as to what this is called but for example if I ran the `console.log(random());` 10 times the result should look a little something like this:

```
>>> "a"
>>> "a"
>>> "a"
>>> "a"
>>> "a"
>>> "a"
>>> "a"
>>> "a"
>>> "b"
>>> "b"
```

`"a"` get's returned 8/10 times and `"b"` gets returned 2/10 times.

**NOTE**: the *"results"* above are just an example, I understand that they won't always be that perfect and they don't have to be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quickest answer would be:

```
var result = Math.random() >= 0.2 ? "a" : "b";
```

Comment: Since 0 is inclusive and 1 is not, your `Math.random() > 0.2 ? 'a':'b'` is saying 79% chance choose `a` and 21% chance choose `b`.  I think you mean for `>=`, which would make it 80/20 as desired in the OP.

Comment: @vol7ron I guess it'll be more like 79.9999999999999999% but still, you're right :)

Comment: @MichałSałaciński yeah something to that affect ;)

Answer (score 3):

**Generalized solution for any number of values**

```
function biasedRandomSelection(values, probabilities) {
    // generate random number (zero to one).
    var rand = Math.random();

    // cumulative probability, starting at 0
    var cumulativeProb = 0;

    // loop through the raw `probabilities` array
    for(var i=0; i<probabilities.length; i++) {
        // increment cumulative probability
        cumulativeProb += probabilities[i];

        // test for `rand` being less than the cumulative probaility;
        // when true, return return the corresponding value.
        if(rand < cumulativeProb) return values[i];
    }
}
```

The knack here is to test against a rolling "cumulative probability", derived from the raw probabilities.

Sample calls :

```
biasedRandomSelection(['a', 'b'], [0.8, 0.2]); // as per the question
biasedRandomSelection(['a', 'b'], [0.2, 0.8]); // reversed probailities
biasedRandomSelection(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], [0.4, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1]); // larger range of values/probailities
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jjv7oLsd/)**

As written, `biasedRandomSelection()` performs no range checking.

A safer version would check that :

- `values` and `probabilities` were congruant
- the sum of the `probabilities` was 1.

Answer (score 2):

[`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) returns a number in [0;1). Just use `p < 0.2` / `p < 0.8` to have a biased result instead of the the unbiased `p < 0.5`.

If you want the first N outcomes to be deterministic, then you can use a simple counter `i++ < N`.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, appreciate it.

Comment: Just for my information: [0;1) , does that mean inclusive 0, exclusive 1? ( in my country it would be written [0;1[  ... thats why im asking)

Comment: @Jonasw Yes, that’s exactly what it means.

Answer (score 1):

A bit extended:

```
var array="a".repeat(8)+"b".repeat(2);
var random=()=>array[Math.floor(Math.random()*array.length)];

alert(random());
```

This also works for more than two results and all different kinds of probability.

Note that array is not really an array but rather a lookupstring
..

http://jsbin.com/besapetidi/edit?console

Comment: This is one of those things that makes you say *"I can't believe I didn't think of this"*  thanks for taking the time to answer.

Comment: @mango congratulations! You won the price *the friendliest and most motivated OP on SO!* ... ;)

Comment: Haha  Thanks! It's been a **really** long day and any help I can get is just *WOW*.

Comment: 4 `a`s and 1 `b` would be sufficient.

Comment: @xufox this answer is not focused on performance but rather on understandability...